# Remove single word after keyword

Tags: python

Python Script to remove names after 'Dear' keyword
I have a string of case comments and I am trying to remove people's name after the word 'Dear'. For example, my string might be 'Dear Jane, I am having an issue with one of the products.' and I want my script to find 'Dear' and then remove the following word 'Jane'. My script identifies 'Dear', but deletes everything after not just the name:

```
text = 'Dear Jane, I am having an issue with one of the products.'

text = ''.join(text.partition('Dear')[:2])

print(text)
```

Comment: Do you want to leave `Dear`? So it says `Dear, I am having...`

Comment: No, it can be deleted along with the name too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leave **`Dear`**, but remove the name, you can use a regular expression and **`re.sub`** here:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(Dear)\s\w+', r'\1', text)
'Dear, I am having an issue with one of the products.'
```

If you want to remove **`Dear`** too, you can change your regular expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r'Dear\s\w+[^\w]+', '', text)
'I am having an issue with one of the products.'
```

Comment: How would you edit the script if it were 'Dear John Smith' and wanted to remove both names?

Comment: Is there always going to be a comma after the `Dear whatever`?

Comment: No, there will not always be a comma

Comment: Then unfortunately there's not really a general method that can detect whether 1 or 2 words need to be removed, without comparing the names against a list of possible names, etc

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I have not found a master list of names to refer to so that I can remove all names. I didn't know if there was a way to remove the first two words after the keyword 'Dear'

Comment: It's easy to remove the first two words after the keyword.  It would just be `re.sub(r'(Dear)(\s\w+){2}', r'\1', text)`, but determining whether or not 2 words or one word need to be removed is the tricky part

Comment: No worries, this alone is extremely useful. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, if this answered your question, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

For any advanced text processing use `re` builtin module:

```
import re
text = 'Dear Jane, I am having an issue with one of the products.'

print(re.sub('^Dear\s(.*?),', 'Dear,', text))
```

Output:

> Dear, I am having an issue with one of the products.